# Better way to access an Assoc list in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a weather getting app that I am working on and I am having a bit of trouble with assoc lists. I have the following list returned from my get-weather function using openweathermap and convert-to-json:

```
((:COORD (:LON . -123.12) (:LAT . 49.25))
 (:WEATHER
  ((:ID . 500) (:MAIN . "Rain") (:DESCRIPTION . "light rain") (:ICON . "10n")))
 (:BASE . "cmc stations")
 (:MAIN (:TEMP . 281.56) (:PRESSURE . 1001) (:HUMIDITY . 93)
  (:TEMP--MIN . 276.15) (:TEMP--MAX . 283.15))
 (:WIND (:SPEED . 3.1) (:DEG . 100)) (:CLOUDS (:ALL . 90)) (:DT . 1453467600)
 (:SYS (:TYPE . 1) (:ID . 3359) (:MESSAGE . 0.0039) (:COUNTRY . "CA")
  (:SUNRISE . 1453478139) (:SUNSET . 1453510389))
 (:ID . 6173331) (:NAME . "Vancouver") (:COD . 200))
```

And I am trying to access the :weather :main rain. Currently I am doing:

```
(cdr (second (second (assoc :weather *assoc-list-from-above*))))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: If this is using cl-json, you may want to consider decoding the json into a firm other than an association list.  I think the documentation describes ways to do that. E.g., if you define a class whose fields match what you're expecting, you could get an instance of that.

Comment: It's a list, not an array.

Comment: Sorry I messed that up when I wrote it.

Comment: @phlie Do you always just want `:weather :main` - in which case I would suggest `(cdr (assoc :main (second (assoc :weather report))))` - or are you looking for a generic way to access any of the fields?

Comment: A generic way to access any of the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the values a lot, you'll probably want to turn the alist into a CLOS object. The json-library might have something to help you do it, but here's an example for doing the weather part manually. You can do the rest similiarly.

```
(defparameter *data*
  '((:COORD (:LON . -123.12) (:LAT . 49.25))
    (:WEATHER
     ((:ID . 500) (:MAIN . "Rain") (:DESCRIPTION . "light rain") (:ICON . "10n")))
    (:BASE . "cmc stations")
    (:MAIN (:TEMP . 281.56) (:PRESSURE . 1001) (:HUMIDITY . 93)
     (:TEMP--MIN . 276.15) (:TEMP--MAX . 283.15))
    (:WIND (:SPEED . 3.1) (:DEG . 100)) (:CLOUDS (:ALL . 90)) (:DT . 1453467600)
    (:SYS (:TYPE . 1) (:ID . 3359) (:MESSAGE . 0.0039) (:COUNTRY . "CA")
     (:SUNRISE . 1453478139) (:SUNSET . 1453510389))
    (:ID . 6173331) (:NAME . "Vancouver") (:COD . 200)))

;; Define classes for the parts that you're interested in.
;; You can leave out the slots you don't need.
(defclass weather ()
  ((id :initarg :id :reader id)
   (main :initarg :main :reader main)
   (description :initarg :description :reader description)
   (icon :initarg :icon :reader icon)))

;; This just decodes the :weather part.
(defun decode-weather (alist)
  (make-instance 'weather
                 :id (cdr (assoc :id alist))
                 :main (cdr (assoc :main alist))
                 :description (cdr (assoc :description alist))
                 :icon (cdr (assoc :icon alist))))

(defparameter *weather* (decode-weather (second (assoc :weather *data*))))

(id *weather*)          ; => 500
(main *weather*)        ; => "Rain"
(description *weather*) ; => "light rain"
(icon *weather*)        ; => "10n"
```

**Edit:** Adding to the other options: You could look at the [`json-bind`](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/#JSON-BIND) utility.

```
(defparameter *json* "{\"foo\": {\"bar\": 5, \"quux\": 10, \"foobar\":[1, 2, 3]}}")
(json:json-bind (foo.bar
                 foo.quux
                 foo.foobar)
    *json*
  (format t "bar: ~a~%quux: ~a~%foobar: ~a~%" 
          foo.bar foo.quux foo.foobar))
;; output:   
;;   bar: 5
;;   quux: 10
;;   foobar: (1 2 3)
```

Borrowing `*input*` from Joshua:

```
(defparameter *input*
  "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":-123.12,\"lat\":49.25},\"weather\":{\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10n\"},\"base\":\"cmc stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":281.56,\"pressure\":1001,\"humidity\":93,\"temp--min\":276.15,\"temp--max\":283.15},\"wind\":{\"speed\":3.1,\"deg\":100,\"clouds\":{\"all\":90}},\"dt\":1453467600,\"sys\":{\"sunrise\":1453478139,\"sunset\":1453510389},\"id\":6173331,\"name\":\"Vancouver\",\"cod\":200}")

(json:json-bind (weather.main
                 sys.sunrise) *input*
  (format t "Weather main: ~a~%Sys surise: ~a~%" weather.main sys.sunrise))
```

**Another edit:** If you have multiple `weather`s, your best option is to go with CLOS (either my option or Joshuas). If you need to use other fields besides weather too, you can combine the two solutions I gave:

```
(json:json-bind (weather sys.sunrise) *input*
  (format t "sys sunrise: ~a~%" sys.sunrise)
  (loop 
     for w in weather
     for dw = (decode-weather w)
     do (format t "Weather: ~a, ~a~%" (main dw) (description dw))))
```

If you don't want to use CLOS, you could do this too:

```
(defun decode-weather-2 (alist)
  (list (cdr (assoc :main alist))
        (cdr (assoc :description alist))))

(json:json-bind (weather sys.sunrise) *input*
  (format t "sys sunrise: ~a~%" sys.sunrise)
  (loop 
     for w in weather
     for (main description) = (decode-weather-2 w)
     do (format t "Weather: ~a, ~a~%" main description)))
```

Comment: This method would work, but CL-JSON provides ways to decode directly to CLOS objects. See [The CLOS decoder](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/#CLOS-DECODER) in the manual.  That seems like it'd be an ultimately cleaner way than decoding to an alist, and then decoding the alist to a CLOS object.  It looks like the object decoder produces an instance of an anonymous class (at which point you could still do `(slot-value obj 'icon)`, etc.), and then a simple call to [`change-class`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_chg_cl.htm) with the target class could do the rest.

Comment: The CLOS decoder in the manual doesn't have an example of a two dimensional JSON. I am a bit lost because of the other dimension.

Comment: @phile can you provide a sample of the JSON you're working with in the question?  From the output, we could reconstruct it, but that's rather tedious.

Comment: @Joshua `{"coord":
{"lon":145.77,"lat":-16.92},
"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"base":"cmc stations",
"main":{"temp":293.25,"pressure":1019,"humidity":83,"temp_min":289.82,"temp_max":295.37},
"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":150},
"clouds":{"all":75},
"rain":{"3h":3},
"dt":1435658272,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":8166,"message":0.0166,"country":"AU","sunrise":1435610796,"sunset":1435650870},
"id":2172797,
"name":"Cairns",
"cod":200}` - Note that `weather` is an array.

Comment: @GavinLock In the original question, the value of weather is in `(:WEATHER
  ((:ID . 500) (:MAIN . "Rain") (:DESCRIPTION . "light rain") (:ICON . "10n")))`, which is just an alist, which is what CL-JSON decodes an object as.  What makes you say that it should be an array?

Comment: @Joshua In the JSON it is an array. All the other keys are either simple values (`"dt":1435658272, "name":"Cairns", "cod":200`) or JS associative arrays (`"coord": {"lon":145.77,"lat":-16.92}`) - but weather is an array of associative arrays. So to read from `weather` we need `(cdr (assoc :main (second (assoc :weather report))))` (to read from the *first* weather entry), but to read from `coord`, `wind`, etc we need `(cdr (assoc :lon (cdr (assoc :coord report))))`

Comment: @GavinLock Yes, you're right, of course.  If the value had simply been an object, then the result would have been `(:weather . ((:id ...) ...))`, which would be *printed* as `(:weather (:id ...) ...)`, which is not what we have.  Good catch!

Comment: 'json:json-bind' works perfectly except when there are multiple response it only displays the last one. For example ' (:WEATHER
  ((:ID . 500) (:MAIN . "Rain") (:DESCRIPTION . "light rain") (:ICON . "10n"))
  ((:ID . 701) (:MAIN . "Mist") (:DESCRIPTION . "mist") (:ICON . "50n"))
  ((:ID . 741) (:MAIN . "Fog") (:DESCRIPTION . "fog") (:ICON . "50n")))' with json:json-bind returns "fog" when I would like it to return rain.

Comment: Do you always need to get only the first item in `weather`? I added examples for looping over multiple `weather`s, but you can easily remove the loop and just decode the first `weather`. In the second example you can change `decode-weather-2` to return `(values ...)` instead of `(list ...)` and then use `(multiple-value-bind (main description) (decode-weather-2 (car weather)) ...)` to get the values outside of `loop`.

Answer (score 4):

While I really like @jkiiski's `json-bind` solution, I thought I'd add the following option as well.

**If the query path is known at compile-time**, you could use the following macro

```
(defmacro report-get (report &optional key &rest keys)
  (cond
   ((null key) report)
   ((integerp key) `(report-get (nth ,key ,report)  ,@keys))
   (t `(report-get (cdr (assoc ,key ,report)) ,@keys))))
```

examples:

```
CL-USER> (report-get *array-from-above* :weather 0 :main)
"Rain"

CL-USER> (report-get *array-from-above* :coord :lon)
-123.12

CL-USER> (macroexpand '(report-get *array-from-above* :weather 0 :main))
(CDR (ASSOC :MAIN (NTH 0 (CDR (ASSOC :WEATHER *ARRAY-FROM-ABOVE*)))))
T
```

The  `0` in `(report-get *array-from-above* :weather 0 :main)` is to access the first item in the collection of weather items

**Edit**: forgot to mention - this macro is `setf`-able.

```
CL-USER> (report-get *array-from-above* :weather 0 :main)
"Rain"
CL-USER> (setf (report-get *array-from-above* :weather 0 :main) "Sunny")
"Sunny"
CL-USER> (report-get *array-from-above* :weather 0 :main)
"Sunny"
```

Probably not useful for your requirement, but nice to know.

Answer (score 3):

First, it might be sufficient to just make your access into the association list a bit cleaner using some intermediate variables. First, let's define an input string that we can parse (in the future, please try to provide these in the question, as they'll help others provide answers):

```
(defparameter *input*
  "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":-123.12,\"lat\":49.25},\"weather\":[{\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10n\"}],\"base\":\"cmc stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":281.56,\"pressure\":1001,\"humidity\":93,\"temp--min\":276.15,\"temp--max\":283.15},\"wind\":{\"speed\":3.1,\"deg\":100,\"clouds\":{\"all\":90}},\"dt\":1453467600,\"sys\":{\"sunrise\":1453478139,\"sunset\":1453510389},\"id\":6173331,\"name\":\"Vancouver\",\"cod\":200}")
```

Now, here's how you could extract the value of the main field of the weather field a bit more cleanly, in my opinion:

```
(let* ((report (cl-json:decode-json-from-string *input*))
       (weather (first (cdr (assoc :weather report))))
       (main (cdr (assoc :main weather))))
  main)
;;=> "Rain"
```

If you'll be making repeated calls to **(cdr (assoc …))** like this, then a function to do this based on a provided path will help a lot, as shown in [Rainer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34949356/1281433).  Of course, the array indexes (e.g., that you want the first element of the weather list) makes things a little less clean.

Now, you also decode to CLOS instances.  CL-JSON can decode JSON into instances of anonymous CLOS classes.  Doing that alone will change the access a little bit, but not by much.  Still, it makes it a little bit clearer how the field access it working.  Note that since the weather value is now an array, not a list, we get the first element with **(aref array 0)**, not **(first list)**.

```
(json:with-decoder-simple-clos-semantics
  (let ((json:*json-symbols-package* nil))
    (let* ((report (json:decode-json-from-string *input*))
           (weather (aref (slot-value report 'weather) 0))
           (main (slot-value weather 'main)))
      main)))
;;=> "Rain"
```

Now, I think the real benefit in using CLOS classes is that you can define your own, and then use [**change-class**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_chg_cl.htm) to change the instance that CL-JSON gives you into an instance of your own class. 
Defining the class in your code also helps greatly in documentation.  That might not seem like a big deal for a small example, but in writing maintainable code, it's very important.  For instance, we can now document the expected types of these slots, and their meanings.  Here's a workable class definition.  Note that people have different opinions about naming conventions (e.g., whether to use **wreport-weather** as the accessor or **weather**).

```
(defclass wreport ()
  ((coord
    :accessor wreport-coord
    :documentation "An object with LON and LAT slots.")
   (weather
    :accessor wreport-weather
    :documentation "An array of objects with ID, MAIN, DESCRIPTION, and ICON slots.")
   (base) ;; and so on ...
   (main)
   (wind)
   (dy)
   (sys)
   (id)
   (name)))
```

Now you can use **change-class** to turn your object into a **wreport**, and then you can use **wreport-weather** (along with **aref**, since the value is still an array) to get the subobject, and then you can use **slot-value** (as above), to get the main field:

```
(json:with-decoder-simple-clos-semantics
  (let ((json:*json-symbols-package* nil))
    (let ((x (json:decode-json-from-string *input*)))
      (let* ((wreport (change-class x 'wreport))
             (weather (aref (wreport-weather wreport) 0))
             (main (slot-value weather 'main)))
        main))))
;;=> "Rain"
```

It probably makes sense to define a subclass for the weather elements, and that's not too hard.  Since we called the top level thing **wreport**, we can call the lower level things **subreport**s:

```
(defclass subreport ()
  ((id
    :accessor subreport-id
    :documentation "")
   (main
    :accessor subreport-main
    :documentation "A short string containing a concise description of the weather.")
   (description
    :accessor subreport-description
    :documentation "...")
   (icon
    :accessor subreport-icon
    :documentation "...")))
```

Now, the only thing left to do is that after we use **change-class** to change the top level report into an instance of **wreport**, we need to call **change-class** for each element in its weather array to turn it into a **subreport**.  According to the documentation of [**change-class**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_chg_cl.htm), [**update-instance-for-different-class**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_update.htm#update-instance-for-different-class) is called.  We can just define an **:after** method on that do the conversion for us:

```
(defmethod update-instance-for-different-class :after (previous (current wreport) &rest initargs &key &allow-other-keys)
  "When changing an instance of something into a WREPORT, recursively
change the elements of the WEATHER array (if bound) to elements of
SUBREPORT."
  (declare (ignore initargs))
  (when (slot-boundp current 'weather)
    (loop for sub across (wreport-weather current)
       do (change-class sub 'subreport))))
```

If you haven't done much with CLOS, that might be a bit intimidating, but you're essentially saying  "after **change-class** has done all its work, also do this one more transformation.  Now you can use domain appropriate accessors at both levels:

```
(json:with-decoder-simple-clos-semantics
  (let ((json:*json-symbols-package* nil))
    (let ((x (json:decode-json-from-string *input*)))
      (let* ((wreport (change-class x 'wreport))
             (subreport (aref (wreport-weather wreport) 0))
             (main (subreport-main subreport))) ;; (slot-value subreport 'main)))
        main))))
;;=> "Rain"
```

This might seem like a lot of work to do, and for a quick little script, it very well might be.  However, if you're going to need these structures for a while, having the documentation cooked into the code will be helpful.  And if you need to *construct* any weather reports, having a good domain model will help a lot.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. I'll wait to see your nested example.

Comment: @phlie OK, that took a bit longer than expected, but I think it's done now.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function, where you pass an access path:

```
(defun get-data (list attributes)
  (flet ((get-it (attribute)
           (if (listp attribute)
               (destructuring-bind (key extractor) attribute
                 (funcall extractor (cdr (assoc key list))))
             (cdr (assoc attribute list)))))
    (if (cdr attributes)
        (get-data-list (get-it (first attributes)) (rest attributes))
      (get-it (first attributes)))))
```

An element in the path can be a key or a list of (key extractor). The extractor needs to be a function which extracts the data from the returned assoc list item.

```
(defparameter *data*
  '((:COORD (:LON . -123.12) (:LAT . 49.25))
    (:WEATHER
     ((:ID . 500) (:MAIN . "Rain") (:DESCRIPTION . "light rain") (:ICON . "10n")))
    (:BASE . "cmc stations")
    (:MAIN (:TEMP . 281.56) (:PRESSURE . 1001) (:HUMIDITY . 93)
     (:TEMP--MIN . 276.15) (:TEMP--MAX . 283.15))
    (:WIND (:SPEED . 3.1) (:DEG . 100))
    (:CLOUDS (:ALL . 90)) (:DT . 1453467600)
    (:SYS (:TYPE . 1) (:ID . 3359) (:MESSAGE . 0.0039) (:COUNTRY . "CA")
     (:SUNRISE . 1453478139) (:SUNSET . 1453510389))
    (:ID . 6173331)
    (:NAME . "Vancouver")
    (:COD . 200)))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 22 > (get-data *data* '((:weather first) :main))
"Rain"

CL-USER 23 > (get-data *data* '((:weather first) :icon))
"10n"

CL-USER 24 > (get-data *data* '(:main :temp))
281.56
```

Tasks:

- make it more robust, etc.
- deal with different lists: assoc lists, property lists, lists with items, ...